# Error when writing a function to create new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
 id |start|stop|join_date
 233| 0   | 12 |2015-01-01
 234| 0   | 12 |2013-03-04
 235| 10  | 23 |2014-01-10
```

**GOAL:**

I want to create another column `stop_date` that offsets the `join_date` based on whether or not the `start` date is 0.

If the `start` is 0 then  `stop_date` is the `join_date` is offset by the months in `stop`

If the `start` is not 0 then  `stop_date` is the `join_date` is offset by the months in `stop` and the months in `start`

I wrote the following function:

```
def stop_date(x):
    if x['start'] == 0:
        return x['join_date'] + x['stop'].astype('timedelta64[M]')
    elif x['start'] != 0 :
        return x['join_date'] + x['start'].astype('timedelta64[M]') + x['stop'].astype('timedelta64[M]')
    else:
        return x
```

I tried to apply to the dataframe by:

```
df['stop_date'] = df.apply(stop_date, axis = 1)
```

I keep getting an error : AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'astype'", 'occurred at index 0')
I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. It seems rather clear to me, what specifically do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when start is 0, doing the sum of start and stop won't change the number of month to add, you can `sum` both, convert with `astype` and add the 'join_date':

```
df['stop_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['join_date']) 
                   + df[['start', 'stop']].sum(axis=1).astype('timedelta64[M]')
                  ).dt.date

print (df)
    id  start  stop   join_date   stop_date
0  233      0    12  2015-01-01  2016-01-01
1  234      0    12  2013-03-04  2014-03-04
2  235     10    23  2014-01-10  2016-10-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the columns to the desired dtype before you apply the function. `x['stop']` is a scalar value of the datatype of the column (e.g., 12), so it has no dataframe or series methods, such as `astype`.